# Ubuntu 18.04.3 Unable to set desired secondary screen resolution

Tags: display-resolution, xrandr

Using version 18.04.3 LTS with a GeForce FT 710 graphics card, and identical HP 27" monitors that support 2560x1440 resolution, I'm unable to set the resolution higher than 1920x1080 on the second monitor. The first monitor resolution is fine.

Here's what the "Settings", "Devices", "Displays" dialog looks like for each of the two monitors:

Monitor 1:
[shows resolution of 2560 x 1440 selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xitt.png)

Monitor 2:
[shows maximum resolution of 1920 x 1080 available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taRbm.png)

I've tried using the xrandr/cvt/newmode commands to create the higher resolution for the second monitor:

`jim@Triton:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4480 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   1920x1200     59.88

   1920x1080     60.00

   1680x1050     59.95

   1600x1200     60.00

   1600x900      60.00

   1440x900      59.89

   1280x1024     75.02

   1280x800      59.81

   1280x720      60.00

   1024x768      75.03    60.00

   800x600       75.00    60.32

   640x480       75.00    59.94

HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected 1920x1080+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95

   1600x1200     60.00

   1600x900      60.00

   1440x900      59.89

   1280x1024     75.02

   1280x800      59.81

   1280x720      60.00

   1024x768      75.03    60.00

   800x600       75.00    60.32

   640x480       75.00    59.94

  2560x1440_60.00 (0x2d4) 312.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2752 end 3024 total 3488 skew    0 clock  89.52KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1493           clock  59.96Hz`

but, when I run the xrandr --addmode command I get this error message:

`sudo xrandr --addmode DVI-D-0 "2560x1440_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  37
  Current serial number in output stream:  38`

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, use of the command 'cvt 2560 1440 60' and set exact mode parameters. https://youtu.be/MScLD8dFNwk

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, that how I added the "2560x1440_60.00" new mode shown above. The commands I used were:

`
jim@Triton:~$ cvt 2560 1440 60
# 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
`

and

`
jim@Triton:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
`

Comment: --addmode DVI-D-0, why this? --addmode DVI-"I"-1 allows 2560 x 1440, not the DVI-D port, right?

Comment: The DVI-I-1 port is my primary monitor. I don't have any issues doing the higher resolution on the primary monitor. The problem is I am unable to set the resolution of the secondary monitor (connected to DVI-D-0) higher than 1920x1080. 
The graphics card is a GT 710, having two DVI dual link connectors I use to connect to identical monitors.

Comment: FT710 has 3 ports, HDMI, DVI and VGA, one of your display is plugged into the VGA port? that's why you can't assign 2560x1440 due to the limitation of VGA? If so, I suggest using a HDMI cable instead.

Comment: The board is an EVGA GeForce GT710, part number 02G-P3-2717-KR, 2GB memory. It has 3 display ports: a DVI-I, a DVI-D, and an mHDMI. Looks like this: https://webobjects2.cdw.com/is/image/CDW/4469448?$product-main$

Comment: It seems like a problematic product. https://forums.evga.com/710-GT-monitor-support-question-m2803134.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response Sadaharu. Reading through the evga formum thread you reference, the moderator is indicating (Nov 21, 2019 posting) that the card will support two Apple Cinema 30" monitors at 2560 x 1600 resolution simultaneously. My monitors are lower resolution than the Apple Cinema monitors. 

Also, earlier postings within the EVGA forum also indicate the maximum total digital resolution supported is 8,294,400 (March 18,2018 posting); the total resolution required for my monitors is 2x2560x1440 or 7,372,800 pixels which is within the maximum.

I've posted my issue in that forum.

Comment: I've found a workaround to this issue, it's a suggestion made by Sadaharu; I've obtained a mHDMI pigtail adapter to used for the second monitor, instead of using the DVI-D connector and I was able to get the higher resolution for my secondary monitor.